# Azure DevOps Ephemeral agents not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agent, azure-container-instances

I am trying to configure an Ephemeral agent in Azure DevOps (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-ephemeral-agents) but it does not work :(

I created the Azure services: A container registry, one VNET with one subnet and one NGS asociated to it, and finaly one storage connected with the VNET.

[image: List of Azure resources]
[image: List of Azure resources]

Then I created a reposotory in the container registry from the official GitHub proyect (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-ephemeral-agents/tree/master/AgentImages/Basic/Ubuntu)

[image]

In Azure DevOps I created an agent pool and a personal token with required permissions to read and manage agent pools. Finaly I configured the task:

[image]

When I launch my pipepline, the container instance is created, but it seems it cant't create the agent, cause is always waiting and finaly the pipeline fails.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have try a lot of configurations and variations, but allways same behaibor. I don't have more ideas. Anyone are running ephemeral? What's is my mistake? any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved my problem. My fault was I used the base OS docker image, not the ephemeral image :(
When I have created the image correctly in the repository, it works!

Comment: I am also trying the same. But for me, once job is done, agent is not visible in the DevOps portal as expected. But in azure portal, container instance is still available, not yet deleted automatically though it's stopped. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to notice the following items:

1. You have to have a dedicated subnet in your virtual network just to run the ephemeral agents.
2. The agent must be running in the same Azure location as the virtual network.
3. Azure Resource Manager Service service connections that use certificates are not supported.

Also, check the sample pipeline to see whether it helps you:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-ephemeral-agents#sample-pipeline

Comment: My Azure DevOps instance is in East US 2 and my Virtual Network is in West Europe. Maybe it is the problem. I am going to check.